# Cartoon with magical gauntlets and underwater city

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

So a few years ago, I used to watch this cartoon with my dad around 5 years ago and I can't remember for the life of me what it was. Here's all the stuff I can remember:

- The story and magic were based on these magical gauntlet/glove thingies that all the main characters wore on one of their hands
- Plot-driven
- The main character black hair and an outfit with lots of red
- I feel like the title started with a "k" but I'm not entirely sure (sorry, that's probably very unhelpful)
- A big bad villain
- A sidekick sort of character for the main guy and some girl
- An underground place with a library and scrolls and lots of brown rock
- An underwater city at some point (I'm pretty sure)
- It's an American cartoon

If anyone has any idea at all what this might be, please let me know.

Comment: Were there five main characters? Did they drive/fly around in vehicles (jets, space ships, ground vehicles, etc.?)

Comment: How many years ago was this? Three, five, ten? Did you see it on TV or internet streaming, and in what country? Also, regardless of where you saw it, do you think it was originally a Japanese anime series, an American cartoon, a European cartoon...?

Comment: It was around 5 years ago, I think, and no to the five main characters with vehicles. Pretty sure it was American.

Comment: And yet another answer from me:
From the makers of Redakai, Conquer the Kairu comes:
[Kaijudo, rise of the Duel Monsters][3]

Also black haired kid wearing red, girl and funny large guy and this time gloves are much more prominent.

Check it out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=8&v=h-J76zkn9cU

  [3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo

Comment: Oh my goodness that's it! Thank you!!

Comment: @jo1storm: You may want to start answering as answers and not as comments.

Comment: I tried. It didn't allow me to post a 3rd answer or edit my previous ones :( I'm glad this one is answered though.

Comment: alternate duplicate target: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203851/cartoon-tv-show-about-three-kids-and-monsters-and-a-veil-between-realms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jo1storm: "And yet another answer from me: From the makers of Redakai, Conquer the Kairu comes: [Kaijudo, rise of the Duel Monsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo)

Also black haired kid wearing red, girl and funny large guy and this time gloves are much more prominent. Check it out:

Answer (score 5):

That sounds to me like [Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series)). It is made according to Yu-Gi-Oh! formula.

> Conquer the Kairu, also known simply as Redakai, is a Canadian/French
>   animated series that premiered on YTV in Canada on July 9, 2011, on
>   Cartoon Network in the United States on July 16, 2011 and on Canal J
>   and Gulli in France on October 22, 2011.

- **The story and magic were based on these magical gauntlet/glove thingies that all the main characters wore on one of their hands**
  *They used gauntlets to summon creatures and pick up magic and cards in some episodes. They used hands from then on*
- **Plot-driven**
  *Overall plot is to collect all of wild redakai*
- **The main character black hair and an outfit with lots of red**
  *Ky Stax is the charismatic leader of the team and he does have black hair and wears lots of red*
- **I feel like the title started with a "k"**
  *Lots of k's in the name*
- **A big bad villain**
  *The guy who is on opposing team fights them on regular basis*
- **A sidekick sort of character for the main guy and some girl**
  *From the linked wiki article, this fits Boomer - If Ky is the chosen one and Maya (the girl) is the mysterious one, then Boomer is the funny one.*

Main characters look like this. [image: Main characters]

- **An underground place with a library and scrolls and lots of brown rock**
  *They visit a place that fits this description in one episode*
- **An underwater city at some point**
  *Ditto*

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the first episode. Since they saw the show on TV, a video should spark their memory better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll add picture as well, because it shows the main characters.

Comment: Nope! Weird how similar it is, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll add another possible answer.

Answer (score 4):

It could also be [Bakugan Battle Brawlers](http://yumegami-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Bakugan_Battle_Brawlers).

> The first episode of the anime television series (produced by TMS Entertainment, Dentsu Inc., and Japan Vistec under the direction of Mitsuo Hashimoto), made its debut in Japan on TV Tokyo on April 5, 2007 and was rebroadcast six days later on BS Japan. Nelvana Limited produced the English-language version and premiered the series on the Canadian network Teletoon in July 2007 and then on Cartoon Network on February 24, 2008.
>
> Dan Kuso's life changed one day when random cards fell out of the sky with special powers. He and his friend Shun invented a game called Bakugan with these. Together with his friends Runo, Marucho, Shun, Julie, and Alice, they form the Bakugan Battle Brawlers and its members are accidentally dragged into fighting for the fate of Vestroia (the Bakugan's home dimension) against the Doom Beings.
>
> The season is the story of a dimension called Vestroia which loses its natural balance and merges with the Earth and many other worlds. An evil Bakugan called Naga was tempted to take the power of the Infinity and Silent Cores, which formed the Perfect Core that balanced Vestroia, but absorbed too much negative energy and thus was trapped within the Silent Core and destabilised Vestroia. So Dan and the brawlers decided to bring back balance by meeting new friends and allies in the other worlds, learn more about the origin of the Bakugan; and facing Naga, a rogue bakugan who seeks the mighty Infinity Core so that he could complete the all-powerful Perfect Core and have almighty power and absolute control over Earth and Vestroia.

Check if this rings any bells.

Main characters wear gloves, main guy wears all red clothes, there's a girl and sidekick.

Comment: Nope- this isn't it either. Thanks, though!